# How to use with Country Name instead of Country Code?

Tags: shipping-methods, magento1.9.2.3, countries

Here is my code about shipping Estimation cost script,

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once('./../app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
ini_set('display_errors',true); 
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
Mage::app()->loadArea('frontend');

function getShippingEstimate($productId,$productQty,$countryId,$postcode ) {

    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('english')->getId());
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

    $_product->getStockItem()->setUseConfigManageStock(false);
    $_product->getStockItem()->setManageStock(false);

    $quote->addProduct($_product, $productQty);
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setcountryId($countryId)->setPostcode($postcode);
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals();
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();

    $_rates = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRatesCollection();

    $shippingRates = array();
    foreach ($_rates as $_rate):
            if($_rate->getPrice() > 0) {
                $shippingRates[] =  array("Title" => $_rate->getMethodTitle(), "Price" => $_rate->getPrice());
            }
    endforeach;

    return $shippingRates;

}

$results = getShippingEstimate('14419','1',"IN","642001"); // Predefined Value

$count = -1;

foreach ($results as $result): 
$count++;
?>
 <option value="<?php echo $result["Price"]; ?>"> <?php echo $result["Title"]." - Rs ".$result["Price"];?> 
 </option>

 <?php
endforeach;

?>
```

How to get shipping cost based on country name instead of country code?

> FYI -  $results = getShippingEstimate('14419','1',"IN","642001");   //IN should be INDIA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$country = Mage::getModel(’directory/country’)->load($country_id);
$countryName = $country->getName();
```

Comment: I am learning stage in PHP, How can i apply with my code? @Peter Horitzer

Comment: code with error : https://paste.ofcode.org/BFKxjt3VBFeSjqxQquYDZE  error : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function load() on boolean in /home/abc/public_html/kolupadi_extension_order/sp_cost.php:14 Stack trace: #0 /home/abc/public_html/kolupadi_extension_order/sp_cost.php(42): getShippingEstimate('14419', '1', 'IN', '642001') #1 {main} thrown in /home/abc/public_html/kolupadi_extension_order/sp_cost.php on line 14

Comment: In your case $country_id should be 'IN'

Alternativ you could try `$country = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->loadByCode($countryCode);`